# How to check current status of gameObject and update to a new animation and check again?

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

I am creating a 2D platform game with Unity and C#. I searching for how I can do the following. 
I have 5 sets of animations and one gameObject(later in game there should be more than one object that can be changed, so maybe we can keep that in mind) with the tag "Campfire0" stored in `anim0` inside the `start function`. What I want is when the user pressed E on his keyboard it will check which is the current animation of the current gameObject and change that animation to "Camfire25" or another number like 50, 75 or 100 and update the gameObject tag. After that is done, it should again check all if statements and the second time you pressed E it should look at the if statement with `if(anim25)` and so on.

**Problem**
Below code I use currently. But the problem is the following. I declare inside the start function the animator of each game object tag, but this will be fired one time if the game is started. After pressing the second time on E, the error "NULL" `NullReferenceException` will occur. So I think I should store the values inside an array? And how should I do that.

For checking which animation is the current one, I use if statements, but can it also be done with a foreach loop or is there a shorter way to do this?

Current Code:

```
public Animator anim0;
public Animator anim25;
public Animator anim50;
public Animator anim75;
public Animator anim100;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

    count = 0;
    setCountText ();
    currentValue = startingValue;
    //anim = GameObject.Find("Campfires").GetComponent<Animator>();                     // Parent of all Campfires
    anim0 = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Campfire0").GetComponent<Animator>();
    anim25 = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Campfire25").GetComponent<Animator>();
    anim50 = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Campfire50").GetComponent<Animator>();
    anim75 = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Campfire75").GetComponent<Animator>();
    anim100 = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Campfire100").GetComponent<Animator>();

}
```

void Update () {

```
        if (inTrigger){

            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E) && count > 0){

                // Update counter on press
                updateCount();

                if (anim0){ 
                    anim0.SetTrigger ("Campfire25");
                    GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Campfire0").transform.tag = "Campfire25";

                }

                if (anim25){
                    Debug.Log ("hello");
                    anim25.SetTrigger ("Campfire50");
                    GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Campfire25").transform.tag = "Campfire50";
                }

                if (anim50){
                    anim50.SetTrigger ("Campfire75");
                    transform.tag = "Campfire75";
                }

                if (anim75){
                    anim75.SetTrigger ("Campfire100");
                    transform.tag = "Campfire100";
                }



            }

        }

    }
```

Above script works for the first time, it will change the campfire tag to "Campfire25" and show another animation clip, after pressing E for the second time  it will give me an error of `NullReferenceException`. This is because the Start Function will be fired ones.

Comment: Are all the gameObject with tag Campfire already in your Hierchy? and did you make sure that they all have an animator with the same anim name?

Comment: GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Campfire0").transform.tag = "Campfire25"; <- this is your problem. Not your Start();

After the Start() is finished referencing your the Animator. 

your if (anim0) <- is still true. Then it will try to access 

anim0.SetTrigger ("Campfire25"); <- which you already set the tag to a different one and it is looking for it.